# Why GOOG is "After Hours" while FB is "Pre-market"?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, after-hours-trading

I used to invest in HK market and weeks before I opened an account in US market. I noticed that there's a "after hours trading". But now (9:22 GMT+0) I found there are two different status from Google Finance view. `Pre-market` vs `After Hours`. So what is the different?

Thanks,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like [GOOG](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/premarket) did not have a pre-market trade until 7:14 am ET, so Google Finance was still reporting the last trade it had, which was in the after-hours session yesterday. [FB](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fb/premarket), on the other hand, was trading like crazy after-hours yesterday and pre-market today as it had an earnings report yesterday.

Answer (score 6):

Pre-Market trading activity is shown on the site from 4:15 - 9:30 AM (actual trading starts at 4:00 AM EST)

The NASDAQ Stock Market Trading Sessions (Eastern Time)

Pre-Market Trading Hours from 4:00 a.m. to 9:30 a.m.

Market Hours from 9:30 a.m. to 4:00 p.m.

After-Market Hours from 4:00 p.m. to 8:00 p.m.

Read more: http://www.nasdaq.com/about/trading-schedule.aspx#ixzz38OtcISrq

In this case GOOG did not trade in the Pre-market until that time and FB was.